# Reading strings with getline into a pointer array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to write a couple of strings (names) into a pointer array. I have written a code that I think logically would do this, but for some reason, it only prints the last string. What could be the solution for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 50

int jatekosell(char* s) {

    int n, ok = 1;

    n = atoi(s);

    if(n<3 || n > 15) 
    {
        printf("Nem jo! 3 es 15 koze kell essen!");
        getline(s, MAX);
        ok = 0;
    }
    return ok;

}

int getline(char *s, int n);

void main() {

    char amount[MAX];
    char name[MAX];
    char *names[MAX];
    int number, i, j;
    printf("Number of players between 3 and 15: ");
    getline(amount, MAX);   
    while(!jatekosell(amount));
    number = atoi(amount);

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        printf("Type the %d. name: ", i+1);
        getline(name, MAX);
        names[i] = name;



    }

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        printf("The names: %s\n", names[i]);

    }




    getchar();

}

int getline(char *s, int n){ 
    int c; 
    char *t=s;
    while(n-- > 0 && (c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n') *t++ = c;
    *t='\0';
    while(c!=EOF&&c!='\n') c=getchar();
    return(t-s); 
}
```

Comment: There is already a `getline` function that is part of the standard library. you should really use another name for your function (say `getln` maybe?)

Comment: And is there a reason for even using that getline when it indeed looks very much like `fgets(,, stdin)`?

Comment: Also [`int main()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c), which to me looks like you're not compiling with warnings enabled at all...

Comment: It's in the C by K&R. I'm used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared a single buffer to `getline()` your data into, `char name[MAX];`.

You read data in there, then "put it into your array" with `names[i] = name;`.

The problem is every element in your array points to the same single buffer and each successive `getline()` just overwrites the contents of that buffer.

You could solve this by replacing `names[i] = name;` with `names[i] = strdup(name);` The `strdup()` function duplicates a string into a dynamically allocated buffer. Be aware though that you now become responsible for releasing that buffer (via `free()`) when you no longer need it.

Another solution would be to replace `char *names[MAX];` with `char names[MAX][MAX];` (to pre-allocate all of your buffers) and `strcpy()` into the next location, but this is probably quite wasteful of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the same memory position (the `name` variable) into each of the `names` array items. You can see that by changing `%s` to `%p` when printing (to show the memory address of `name[i]`).

Instead of just assigning `names[i] = name`, you'll need to copy the contents of `name` into `names[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
names[i] = name;
```

is wrong. You need to use memcpy or you just overwrite the last string each time. You also need to allocate room for the strings you're receiving ie if MAX == 10;

```
char *names[10];
```

is allocating an array of 10 pointers to strings ie there's no room for strings when allocated.

```
char names[10][MAX];
```

This gives you an array of pointers and they can each hold MAX characters. Or you need to malloc them before use ie

```
names[i] = calloc(1, MAX);
size_t name_len = strlen(name);
assert(name_len < MAX);
memcpy(names[i], name, name_len);
names[i][str_len] = '\0';// Null terminate string
```

Comment: How do I use memcpy? 
memcpy(&names[i], name, sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0])); 
This doesn't seem to work.